# How to set the height in iText7

Tags: itext7

I use iText7 to generate PDF file. I want to set the Cell's height. 
I use method setHeight to do it. If the content is less, the cell is OK, but if the content is more, the cell's height is extend. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a method in the `Cell` class called `setMaxHeight()`. However, as you can see in the [API Docs](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.2-SNAPSHOT/com/itextpdf/layout/element/BlockElement.html#setMaxHeight-float-), this method is only available in iText 7.0.2, and that version hasn't been officially released yet.

Comment: Expect iText 7.0.2, Thanks Bruno.

Comment: It should be released in about a month (give or take a week).